Multiple Set-Cookie headers are combined; browser only picks the first cookie
I’m developing a GraphQL API using Apollo Server running on AWS Lambda with API Gateway (using the @as-integrations/aws-lambda package).
In my authentication flow, I need to set three cookies (idToken, accessToken, and refreshToken) when a user logs in.
The problem:
When I send the response from Lambda, all three cookies are combined into a single Set-Cookie header, separated by commas. The browser only picks up the first cookie (idToken) and ignores the rest. As a result, on subsequent requests, only the idToken is sent back to the server, and the accessToken and refreshToken are missing.
I’ve tried various client-side packages like fetch, axios, and graphql-request, but the issue persists, indicating that the problem is on the server side.
Here’s what the response headers look like:
Set-Cookie: idToken=...; Path=/; HttpOnly; Secure; SameSite=None; Max-Age=3600, accessToken=...; Path=/; HttpOnly; Secure; SameSite=None; Max-Age=3600, refreshToken=...; Path=/; HttpOnly; Secure; SameSite; Max-Age=86400

Relevant server code where I set the cookies in the Apollo Server plugin:
const cookiePlugin: ApolloServerPlugin = {
  async requestDidStart() {
    return {
      async willSendResponse(
        requestContext: GraphQLRequestContextWillSendResponse<any>
      ) {
        const { contextValue, response } = requestContext;
        const setCookies = contextValue.setCookies || [];

        if (setCookies.length > 0) {
          response.http.headers.set(
            "Set-Cookie",
            setCookies
              .map((cookie) => {
                const parts = [`${cookie.name}=${cookie.value}`];
                parts.push(`Path=${cookie.options.path}`);
                if (cookie.options.httpOnly) {
                  parts.push("HttpOnly");
                }
                if (cookie.options.secure) {
                  parts.push("Secure");
                }
                parts.push(`SameSite=${cookie.options.sameSite}`);
                parts.push(`Max-Age=${cookie.options.maxAge}`);
                return parts.join("; ");
              })
              .join(", ")
          );
        }
      },
    };
  },
};

In my authentication function, I set the cookies like this:
context.setCookies.push(
  {
    name: "idToken",
    value: IdToken,
    options: {
      ...cookieOptions,
      maxAge: 3600,
    },
  },
  {
    name: "accessToken",
    value: AccessToken,
    options: {
      ...cookieOptions,
      maxAge: 3600,
    },
  },
  {
    name: "refreshToken",
    value: RefreshToken,
    options: {
      ...cookieOptions,
      maxAge: 86400,
    },
  }
);

Server setup:
const publicServer = new ApolloServer({
  typeDefs: publicTypeDefs,
  resolvers: publicResolvers,
  csrfPrevention: false,
  plugins: [cookiePlugin],
});

export const graphqlHandler = startServerAndCreateLambdaHandler(
  publicServer,
  handlers.createAPIGatewayProxyEventV2RequestHandler(),
  {
    context: ctx,
    middleware: [
      async (event) => {
        return async (result) => {
          result.headers = {
            ...result.headers,
            "access-control-allow-headers": "content-type, authorization, recaptcha",
            "access-control-allow-methods": "*",
            "access-control-allow-origin": origin,
            "access-control-allow-credentials": "true",
          };
          return result;
        };
      },
    ],
  }
);

What I’ve tried:

•   Setting response.http.headers['Set-Cookie'] to an array of cookie
strings:
response.http.headers['Set-Cookie'] = cookieStrings;

This resulted in the Set-Cookie headers disappearing completely from the response.

•   Using multiValueHeaders in the Lambda response:

Since I’m using API Gateway V2 (HTTP API), multiValueHeaders doesn’t seem to be supported.

•   Adjusting the middleware to handle headers differently: Tried
modifying the middleware to manipulate headers, but couldn’t get the
multiple Set-Cookie headers to be sent separately.

My understanding:
•   In HTTP, each cookie should be sent in its own Set-Cookie header. Combining them into a single header causes browsers to only accept the first cookie.
•   AWS API Gateway might combine multiple headers with the same name unless they are handled correctly.

Question:
How can I correctly set multiple Set-Cookie headers in the response from AWS Lambda (using API Gateway and Apollo Server), so that the browser picks up all the cookies?
Is there a way to get AWS API Gateway to correctly send multiple Set-Cookie headers from Lambda? Do I need to adjust how I’m setting the headers in the response?
Additional context:

I’m using AWS API Gateway V2 (HTTP API).
The client-side code includes credentials: 'include' in fetch
requests.
The issue persists across different client-side HTTP libraries
(fetch, axios, graphql-request), so I believe the problem is on the
server side.


This has been discussed already

Thank you @WiktorZychla , but as I mentioned,  Setting response.http.headers['Set-Cookie'] to an array of cookie strings, This resulted in the Set-Cookie headers disappearing completely from the response.

You are not the first person in the world, fortunately, who tries this with Apollo.

That guy used the "apollo-server-express" vs apollo v3. but this issue is related to apollo V4 and also my current stack that uses"@as-integrations/aws-lambda". So be sure that I'm currently wasted one week on this issue and reviewed all pages on SOF :)
